# sunspot surely this can be done with some ruby magic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I need to access my rails model instance from inside the searchable block as indicated below.

```
class Product

        include MongoMapper::Document
        include Sunspot::Rails::Searchable

        key :field_names, Array

        searchable do |ss|

            self.field_names.each do |field| 
              ss.double field[:name] do 
                field[:value] 
              end 
            end 
        end

end
```

does anyone know how to do this via Sunspot ?

I have a field_names array on each product instance that is different per product so i need to access it.

Thanks a lot
Rick

Comment: Please just put the code that matters, I don't know why we're looking at three nearly-identical things.

Answer (score 0):

you mean this?

```rb
def Foo

  attr_accessible  :id, :title

  def fields
    ['something']
  end

  searchable do 

    integer :id
    string  :title

    string :fields, :multiple => true do 
      self.fields
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: zagros  thanks but no.   i need to access Foo's instance outside of the string :fields  block not from inside it.    any ideas ?

Comment: That makes no sense - in that execution context, self would be the `Foo` class, not an instance of `Foo`. Sunspot sets up its stuff at class definition time. Instance values have no bearing on it.

Comment: Chris Heald  thanks this is my problem. can you offer a solution?

Comment: i can't find any reference to what i'm trying to demonstrate you but here's the __[closest post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-sunspot/5xanVMY6ekQ)__ ... so to dynamically add fields, you're best bet is the approach above (in 2nd answer) or a modification of it

Comment: I don't think that you're coming at this right. Creating arbitrary searchable fields on your table is going to make those fields searchable for *all* records on that table, not just the ones with that field. This doesn't map well to Sunspot - you may need to roll some custom behavior to get what you want.

Comment: Chris Heald  thanks.   Actually my model is a mongo_mapper not active record but didnt want to confuse if people didnt know mango_mapper.    So different fields for different documents / products.   Does that make more sense ?

Comment: It does, but you basically need to create indexes on all your possible fields. If users can define fields at runtime, that is not going to play well with Solr at all.

Comment: Chris Heald  thanks.   users can not define fields at runtime.  I control the fields being created and they are only a few fields per product category but to get to the fields on the category for a product i need to access the product instance to know which category it is in, to lookup the fields i want to search on for that product.  Does that make more sense ?  sorry was trying to simplify the problem obviously too much!!

Answer (score 0):

well inside there, you're inside a different evaluation context (Solr::DSL or something like that).  That's to provide the ability to have those keywords like "integer, string".  Looks like you're trying to evaluate dynamic attributes/filters ..   .. so see my modified response (below)

you mean this?

```rb
def Foo

  attr_accessible  :id, :title

  @fields_to_dynamically_add = ['title']


  searchable do |s|

    s.integer :id
    s.string  :title

    @fields_to_dynamically_add.each do |f|
      s.string f.to_sym
    end

  end

end
```

**PS:  have not added fields to searchable blocks dynamically every myself (although the above works)**

Comment: zagros thanks but i have updated my question.  is that possible ?